# CMake; 386:x86-64 architecture of input file (.. ) is incompatible with i386 output

Tags: c, cmake, libraries

I get this error when first doing 'cmake build' and then 'make':

```
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `CMakeFiles/eperftool.dir/mp4reader.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `CMakeFiles/eperftool.dir/codec_instance_mgmt.o' is incompatible with i386 output
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `CMakeFiles/eperftool.dir/callbacks.o' is incompatible with i386 output
(...)"
```

This is the format of my make-file:

```
file (GLOB eperftool_sources ./*)

set(EPERFTOOL_BIN ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}/eperftool CACHE STRING "eperftool dir")
add_executable( eperftool ${eperftool_sources})


find_package (Threads)
if (Threads_FOUND)
  include_directories(${Threads_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif (Threads_FOUND)

target_link_libraries(eperftool openfec m)

target_link_libraries(eperftool ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} )

set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-m32")"
```

I added the final line 'set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS "-m32")' after Googling the problem and finding a person that has added the linker-flag '-m32' in order to solve it, but it didn't solve the problem for me.

What should I do in order to solve the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you copied the object files `mp4reader.o, codec_instance_mgmt.o and callbacks.o` from somewhere (not compiled on your system), which is causing incompatibility on your system.
You can try to remove all objects and compile it again:

```
rm *.o
```

and then compile again.

Comment: I run this command 'cmake build clean .. && cmake build .. && make'.

I had another Ubuntu-installation and it worked fine compiling. Ubuntu stopped working so I installed it again using the Window Installer and copied the files from the old system.

Comment: did you try removing old object files?

Comment: Thanks for the help!
I removed the build-directory and built it all again. Now it is working.
Have a nice weekend! /Anders